# What does -라느니 mean?

Tags: translation, conjunctions

I found it from this sentence 
"내가 다른 가문에서 보낸 첩자라느니 암살자라느니" 
But the translation from naver papago is 
"i'd rather be an assassin than a spy from another family"

Idk if that translation is accurate. So, -라느니 used to compare something?

Answer (score 2):

1) 나는 그들이 내 연필이 이쁘다느니 내 가방이 이쁘다느니 하는 말을
들었다.

I hear a word saying *that they talk* that my pencil is pretty and
*that they talk* that my bag is pretty.

2) 그들은 내가 다른 가문에서 보낸 첩자라느니 암살자라느니 말한다

They talk *that I am* a spy from other's family and *that I am* an
assassin from other's family

북한에서는 동무라느니 수령이라느니 이런 말을 쓴다

In north Korea, north Koreans use such words saying that A is 동무
and that B is 수령.

Comment: As for your last sentence, when I searched naver for "쓴다", it returned entries matching 쓰다. Is that a typo?

Comment: 쓰다 is a basic form and 쓴다 is a present continuous.

Answer (score 2):

The naver translation is wrong.

> ~라느니

normally has a negative meaning and it is being used when someone said something that is not true for the speaker's perspectives.

It is not comparing, it is just the way expressing "someone said something", example:

> He told me that I am like an idiot or I am like a useles person!
>
> 그가 내가 바보라느니, 내가 쓸모없다느니 말했다고!

It might be hard to understand so if you try to take it as an expression, it might be easier to learn.