# Why would you ever use -에서?

Tags: difference, postpositions

The following quotation is [from this answer](https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/5153/1412).

> 북한에서는 동무라느니 수령이라느니 이런 말을 쓴다
>
> In north Korea, north Koreans use such words saying that A is 동무 and that B is 수령.

I am trying to understand that first word.

```
북 North
한 Korea
에 at
서 from
는 topic marker
```

The presence of both `에` and `서` seems redundant to me, since "at" and "from" both are locatives so I don't know what their functions are. Also, as the English translation reads "in", I don't see why `서` (which means "from") should be there.

Do these words mean the same thing, and could they be used instead of 북한에서는 in that sentence up there?

- 북한에는
- 북한서는

Why or why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

에서 is not made of 에+서: on the contrary, 서 is considered a *shortened form* of more common 에서.

When describing places (i.e., where it happens), different verbs take either 에 or 에서.  As HK Lee said, -에 is commonly used for verbs that denote a static state, while -에서 is used for activities.

In the sentence in question, "쓴다" is pretty active, so only -에서 is possible.

Sometimes a verb may allow both: I think "서울에 산다" and "서울에서 산다" are both correct.

- Note that 에/에서 may have other uses different from "place".  For example, 에 is commonly used as direction, and 에서 is used as source:

  > 철수는 명동**에서** 두 시간을 걸어 광화문**에** 도착했다.

Answer (score 1):

Usually 에 means 'state' : The money is in my pocket. 그 돈은 내 지갑에 있다.

And 에서 means 'activity' : I used to eat a meal at home. 나는
집에서 밥을 먹곤 했다.

I live in Seoul city. 나는 서울에서 살고 있다.

Lastly, 에서는 means 'comparing' : I saw a movie in his house. But it is impossible in my house,
because of father.

그의 집에서 영화를 봤다. 그러나
우리집에서는 아버지 때문에 불가능하다.

Comment: I'd say '는' is used as a typical "topic marker" here, not necessarily indicating comparison.

Comment: Consider the book title ["회사에서는 왜 이상한 사람이 승진할까"](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=PW1RDwAAQBAJ) It doesn't compare anything, or necessarily imply anything about "다른데" (non-회사). It's just a... topic marker.

Comment: my answer is based on the link https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=24669

Comment: Other real life examples: [iCloud에서는 무엇을 백업합니까?](https://support.apple.com/ko-kr/HT207428) [서울대에서는 누가 A+를 받는가.](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=v58OBQAAQBAJ)  [18일 오전 7시 58분 일본 오사카 에서는규모 5.9의 지진이 발생했다.](http://m.kihoilbo.co.kr/?mod=news&act=articleView&idxno=756023#0B0G) The only common function of -는 added to -에서 is to highlight the noun that precedes -에서 (iCloud, 서울대, 오사카). It doesn't necessarily imply comparison.

Comment: To me, all examples contains comparison. For instance, 고려대에서는 내가 A를 받았는데, 서울대에서는 누가 받았니 ?

Comment: Only because you add a context. In my original examples, the writers apparently have no interest in a system other than iCloud, a university other than Seoul National, or a city other than Osaka. They are just indicating the major interests/topics of the sentences are the said nouns.

Comment: Yes, you *can* use a topic marker to imply comparison. But that's neither the only nor primary use of it.

Comment: I think, `에서는` implies that you do something or whatever event is happened *only* in there. Somewhat similar to the `only if` condition. So it does compare things.

Comment: 집에서는 잠을 자고 헬스장에서는 운동을 했다. -> It makes sense. 
집에서는 잠을 자고 찜질방에서는 잠을 잤다. -> Strange.

Comment: iCloud에서는 음악을 백업합니다. 네이버 클라우드에서는 사진을 백업합니다. -> It makes sense. 
iCloud에서는 음악을 백업합니다. 네이버 클라우드에서는 음악을 백업합니다. -> Strange.

Comment: 일본 오사카에서는 지진이 발생했다. 서울에서는 태풍이 발생했다. -> It makes sense. 
일본 오사카에서는 지진이 발생했다. 포항에서는 지진이 발생했다. -> Strange.

Comment: This made me think. Now I assume `에서는` always involves comparison without an exception. It means `A` is true while `A~` is not. If I wanted to say that the other way I would use `에서` or `에서도`.